# What is the difference between 'element' and 'documentElement'?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between 'element' and 'documentElement' ?

Comment: It is clearly stated in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement

Answer (score 0):

**DOM:**

The DOM is the overall model which represents the whole page as a `TreeView`.
Just like this [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/DOM-model.svg/1920px-DOM-model.svg.png).

**documentElement:**

The documentElement just returns the `<HTML>` or the root element. So basically you can say that documentElement is the first child element from DOM.